# I keep getting this error when trying to create a histogram in ggplot2: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): x

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

For context, I had to create an array as an object with a set of data. Here's my code:

```
#### Array for Histogram ####
array1 = c(24,33,25,34,24,12)
array2 = c(13,13,10,29,38,12,20,22,20,39,26,15,31,29,1,15,22,19,20,13,29,32,4,27)
final = array(c (array1, array2), dim=c(6,5))
print(final)

#### Grouping #### 
finaldata<-data.frame(final)
View(finaldata)

#### Creating Histogram ####
ggplot(finaldata,aes(final))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 30)
```

I'm not really sure which part of this is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no column `final` in the data.frame `final_data`

```
str(finaldata)

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X1: num  24 33 25 34 24 12
 $ X2: num  13 13 10 29 38 12
 $ X3: num  20 22 20 39 26 15
 $ X4: num  31 29 1 15 22 19
 $ X5: num  20 13 29 32 4 27
```

So, you need to use of the variables above, here is an example using X1

```
ggplot(finaldata,aes(X1))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 30)
```

[image]